# What is the best paid proxy service for google search ranking tool?

Tags: proxy, screen-scraping

I'm struggling to find a good and reliable paid proxy service to run a script that reports on organic search results for a set of keywords.

Does anyone have any recommendations? We'll be analyzing 60 keywords against 30 urls per day and our setup is LAMP based using Curl for the script.

Any advice would be welcome.

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

I have had good experience with http://proxybonanza.com and http://packetflip.com

Answer (score 0):

I've had good experience with http://seo-proxies.com , also used on the free rank checker at http://google-rank-checker.squabbel.com
Check the rank checkers ip management functions, they include proper delay and rotation algorithms to avoid getting into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out http://geoedge.com, I used them in the past.

Comment: It's better to provide such shot answers and comments to the post.